# Use auto generated id in another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In some cases we need to duplicate the auto generated id field into another field of the same row.

Is there a way to do this with one INSERT statement instead of going back and doing an update afterwards?

Here's some none working SQL to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (string1, string2, int1)
VALUES ('foo', 'bar', id)
```

Attempting to put the auto generated id into the field 'int1'

Comment: No way to do it in the query, but you could make it a computed column in the table.

Comment: Use a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) with the `persisted` hint.

Comment: The thing is, only some of the rows need this. I don't think the computed column would work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You could use a trigger which does an update immediately following the insert.  That's a good place for the logic to decide if the other column needs the value or not.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the identity value to another column in the same table? What could possibly be the reason for this?

Comment: Definitely don't need a trigger. A case expression in a computed column could handle that easily.

Comment: Another alternative using SQL Server 2012 you can disable identity column and insert it by yourself using a sequence.

CREATE SEQUENCE Test.CountBy1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1 ;

Comment: Not ideal but create a table that is nothing but the iden generator and have your table be a FK to it

Answer (score 0):

try to use sequence like it shown in this link [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx)